# Adding a button to a form that links to an external URL

Tags: forms

I am trying to add another button to a user login form.  I am able to get the button to show up, but not to link to an external URL (example.org in the code below).  Code I am using is below:

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_login' || $form_id == 'user_login_block') {
    $form['change_pass'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="change_pass">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#value' => t('Change Password'),
      '#weight' => 1000,
      '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_change_pass_submit'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    );
  }
}

function MYMODULE_change_pass_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('https://example.org', array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You also have to make sure that $_GET['destination'] is empty: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24815/24446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$form_state['redirect']` to redirect in form submit instead of `drupal_goto`
,I mean

```
function MYMODULE_change_pass_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_state['redirect'] ='https://example.org';
}
```